# Live map geolocation

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I was working on the log in page for a website and wanted to make a [map like this](http://image.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/85409/85409,1215459361,2/stock-vector-abstract-world-map-14626579.jpg) or [this](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/wp-content/uploads/image/free-world-map-black-white.gif) that could display where users are currently connected. Is there a preexisting geolocation API that I can use to make this? I know Google has a Javascript API for their maps, but does it support custom maps like that?

Comment: This question lacks sufficient research effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google maps api supports custom map images;
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes

here is an example;
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image

Comment: plus, you can simple grab users geolocation value with google api, convert data to left and top percentages and create makers on your map depending on those values.